# display content type in view

Tags: views, 7, nodes, entities

I have 2 content types courses and courses_type, I added courses_types as node reference in courses.

when going to build view to dispaly all courses with thier courses_type the courses_type column is empty. what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create a relationship in the view using the specific node reference?

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 7, use the [Entity](http://drupal.org/project/entity) and [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) modules. This is just a simple view. You don't need to create any relationship. Just add course type in Fields.

[image]